# How to take elements from two lists and combine them in a third one (python)?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And I expect the outcome to be something like this, so I can easily access it later:

```
list_c = [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 3], ...]
```

What's the easiest way to do that?

- The two lists have different lengths
- I need every letter in `list_b` to have the five corresponding numbers, basically all possible combinations, because I need to easily access ie. `[c, 4]` later on.

I tried just to append `list_a` and `list_b` to `list_c` but it obviously didn't go as planned.

**I can't use builtin functions such as `zip`, `itertools`, etc.**

Comment: You need to use a double for loop...

Comment: Try use `itertools.product(list_b, list_a)` ?

Comment: "...to be something like..." is a rather imprecise requirement. What if the two lists have different lengths?

Comment: If you're not allowed to use Pythons standard library (is this homework?) then use two nested loops.

Comment: @hstk "*I can't use prebuilt functions such as zip, itertools, etc.*"

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with 2 for statements:

```
list_c = [[b, a] for b in list_b for a in list_a]
```

Output: `[['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 3], ['a', 4], ['a', 5], ['b', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 3], ['b', 4], ['b', 5], ['c', 1], ['c', 2], ['c', 3], ['c', 4], ['c', 5]]`